# In Google Ads, how can I clear the old campaigns, ad groups, and ads and start over?

Tags: google-ads

I haven't used AdWords in a few years. There's all kinds of clutter on the overview from over a decade ago. There are a list of campaigns that I don't need or want there. I really want to start over and can't find any way how to do that. There are ads, which are supposedly enabled belonging to ad groups or campaigns that have been removed. I want the whole thing gone because it's really confusing to try editing an ad when it belongs to a campaign that isn't even there.

**How can I clear all the old campaigns, groups, and ads, and start over?** It would be alright to simply archive them, but I don't want them interfering with me starting new ads.

Answer (score 1):

You can deactivate the entire account and start again from scratch.
Alternatively, you'd have to go through everything set at account-level and remove what you don't want. That means:

- Ad Assets
- Settings
- Audiences
- Conversions
- Negative Keyword Lists
- Bid Adjustments

It's not hard to do this, but do make sure you get it all.

Remember, anything you remove is still there, just removed. It *shouldn't* affect anything that is enabled, but I've noticed that Google have been a little lax in actually enforcing that when it comes to their automated systems. Be warned, removed assets might be used as inspiration for automatically generated new assets.

As for the campaigns, ad groups, actual ads, and keywords, just pausing/removing at the campaign level will prevent these from running. Although any data gleaned from these may affect how automated bid strategies work. Google are a little hazy on how these things work.